# using image file using Share contract

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I have an jpg file that is added in VS project within images folder. I can access its path using following

```
var imagePath = "ms-appx:///images/BookTitle.jpg";
```

I want to use this image in my app share contract. For this I am following the tutorial at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758305.aspx) link. Only issue is that in the tutorial file is selected using filePicker whereas I already have this file within my project. I think I need to use following code but don't know how to set imageFile from imagePath above. Can you please provide any points?

```
request.data.setBitmap(Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.createFromFile(imageFile));
```

Any pointer, how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
request.data.setBitmap(Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.createFromUri(imagePath));
```

Comment: It seems to me that `createFromFile` takes an `IStorageFile`.